# Can I expose geth's rpc ONLY to Metamask connections?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I am building a private chain and rpcaddr is set to 0.0.0.0
But recently I found out that this private chain has been attacked by a foreign IP, it kept trying to transfer those worthless ether out from my account.
The only external connection I need is connection to Metamask, so I was wondering is there any way that the geth only allow metamask to connect, while rpcaddr is set to localhost?

Comment: how about to use 127.0.0.1 address?

Answer (score 1):

When you set rpcaddr set to `0.0.0.0`, it means everyone can access it if they know your node's IP address. You have these options:

1. If MetaMask and your node are on the same **machine**, just set the rpcaddr to `127.0.0.1` and only connections from the same machine will be allowed.
2. If MetaMask and your node are on the same **network**, set rpcaddr to your local **gateway address**
3. If they are both on the different networks you can set rpcaddr to IP address of your other machine (not recommended)
4. Set [authentication](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options) for your node

Comment: This was really helpful. For #2, is there a reason (such as security?) to set it to the local gateway address rather than simply the specific IP address of the host machine? I was able to make this work with the IP address of the host machine but not with the local gateway address of the network. When I attempted the latter, I got the error "bind: cannot assign requested address"

Comment: Also, FYI the docs have been updated so now its http.addr rather than rpc.addr: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/server (please correct me if I'm wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is pass `--rpccorsdomain="metamask extension url"`  as well from your geth console.
Check this post to see how to do: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015290012-Using-a-Local-Node

Comment: FWIW I was able to get this to work without specifying the corsdomain. I tried both ways (with and without) and it worked regardless, at least when interacting with Metamask.